# java client consuming API

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client, mailgun

I am trying to use mail gun API for getting bounce mail data.

```
public static ClientResponse GetBounce() {

     Client client = new Client();
           client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api",
                           "key-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
           WebResource webResource =
                   client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org/" +
                                   "bounces/foo@bar.com");
    return webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);}
```

It works fine API call is ok but I am not able to convert ClientResponse in appropriate type in my cae EmailError .
Actual response from server is `{"address":"a@gmail.com","code":"550","error":"550 5.2.1 The email account that you tried to reach is disabled. lq5si9613879igb.63 - gsmtp","created_at":"Tue, 18 Aug 2015 12:23:35 UTC"}`

I created POJO to map response

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class EmailError {
    private String address;
    private String error;
    private String created_at;
//geters...
//setters..
}
```

And try to map ClientResponse into EmailError type.

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = getBounce(email);
         EmailError error = response.getEntity(new GenericType<EmailError>() {
         });
```

where clientResponse is object return by method `GetBounce()`

```
It throws an Exception com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class com.che.rt.businessservices.EmailError, and Java type class com.che.rt.businessservices.EmailError, and MIME media type application/json;charset=utf-8 was not found
```

Any guess where I am missing.

Comment: Show your dependencies.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the Jackson dependency (as you're using its annotations) but that is not enough for Jersey. Jersey uses `MessageBodyReader`s to deserialize request/response bodies. So you need one that can handle JSON. Jackson does implements a JAX-RS reader and writer. So the dependency you need is the Jackson provider, not just the primary Jackson libraries.

For Jersey you can add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

This will pull in Jackson 1.9.2, so you can get rid of the other Jackson dependencies you have, just so version don't conflict. Then you need to register the Jackson provider with the Jersey client. For that you can do

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getProperties().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
config.getSingletons().add(new JacksonJsonProvider());
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Note the above uses Jackson 1.9.2. If you want to use a newer 2.x Jackson, then instead of the above dependency, use this one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <!-- or whatever [2.2,) version you want to use -->
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then configuration should also be different

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getSingletons().add(new JacksonJsonProvider());
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Comment: same issue  com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.cheasyy.cofinding.businessservices.EmailError, and Java type class  com.che.rt.businessservices.EmailError, and MIME media type application/json;charset=utf-8 was not found
Oct 15, 2015 3:07:40 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json;charset=utf-8 ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App

Comment: Works fine for me. And why are you using `GenericType`? There's nothing generic about `EmailError`

Comment: Yes it is not required I was just trying it. Its working perfect webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);} but can't convert to EmailError

Comment: Give me a minute, I will post a complete test

Comment: Looks like the configuration property doesn't work on the client. If you are using the `jersey-json`, just register the `JacksonJsonProvider` like in the second example.

Comment: now diffrent error                     com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "code" (class com.che.rt.businessservices.EmailError), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "error", "created_at", "address"])
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@7f5789; line: 1, column: 34] (through reference chain: com.cheasyy.cofinding.businessservices.EmailError["code"])

Comment: You need to add the `code` field/property in your class. Look at the JSON